# How do I display an image at a particular size (in mm)?

Tags: photos, graphics, image-editing, adobe-photoshop

I’m trying to use my iPhone as a light source and a digital negative to make analog prints.

For example, the Paper Exposer app generates a light source that when placed behind a 35mm strip of film and a camera, works as an enlarger).

The difficult part is getting a photo to appear at 35mm negative size (22mm by 16mm) so it won’t be cropped by the film camera’s shutter.

Comment: So you want to use a digital picture and imprint that on photo paper?

Comment: The issue that I'm seeing here is that even the iphone 12 with it's 460ppi pixel density can only generate a picture of 430*630 pixels which will be quite noticeable when enlarged.

Comment: You're going to have to better describe your workflow. That app is for controlling light when exposing existing film to photographic paper using a fixed-position lens as an enlarger. That doesn't sound like what you're trying to do. See http://jakubkotrc.com/paper-exposer

Comment: I’ve been trying to make contact prints of a digital photo with my iPhone and iPad, but the results turn out blurry. I’m thinking this might be a focusing issue, so my idea was to basically make an enlarger with the phone as a light source and negative. Set the image as 35mm, and enlarge it by placing it on top of a 35mm camera, so I could adjust the focus and shutter speed.

Comment: I think the pixel density might be an issue, but it could be interesting to try, even if just for 4 x 6 prints.

Comment: I don't think "interesting" quite describes it. You have set yourself a task that won't work even if you get it right. Just take the photos to a high street photo shop. It's actually difficult to describe how far in the wrong direction you're trying to go with this idea & how much film you're likely to waste trying to get it to work.